# React native svg not rendered correct

Tags: react-native, react-native-svg

We are working on a Vue/ReactNative project and have the strange phenomenon that in the
Reactnative component react-native-svg (version 12.1.0) the SVG is not rendered correctly.
In the browser it is rendered correctly.

The SVG itself was created with Adobe and uses CSS styles. Are not all CSS elements supported ?

We use the SVGs dynamically from an external Uri and not as a static file.

```
<svg-css-uri
    :key="'image_' + selectedItem.id"
    :height="200"
    :uri="selectedItem.picture.url"
  ></svg-css-uri>
</view>
    
    
mystyle: {
  marginLeft: 25,
  flex: 0.5,
  justifyContent: "center",
}
```

should like this

[image]

looks like this (wrong)

[image]

Comment: Can you somehow post a download link of your svg file? I would test it in my environment

Comment: @Arbnor sure here is the direct link https://msoss-app.sos-ch-dk-2.exo.io/Viola_O_cd75f584f9.svg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 ways to use SVG images using `react-native-svg`

#### 1. Converting to react components

You can convert your svg image to react components by using this [playground](https://react-svgr.com/playground/?native=true).

Note: there is also a possibility to convert the image via CLI but I prefer playground as it is easier.

#### 2. Using SVG files directly

For this, you might want to flow the steps mentioned in the docs [here](https://github.com/react-native-svg/react-native-svg#use-with-svg-files)

Comment: We use the SVGs dynamically from an external Uri, did I understand it correctly that we can use "react-native-svg-transformer" for our case ?

Comment: May be you should try this inside `.svgrrc`

https://github.com/kristerkari/react-native-svg-transformer/issues/11#issuecomment-484056625

Answer (score 2):

I was able to render the SVG on iOS under React Native as follows:
https://www.codepile.net/pile/7AP5vlmn (use this code)

Using https://react-svgr.com/playground/, I converted the SVG into a React Native component. You can then easily import and render from a .js file. This is how it looks on the iOS Simulator:

[image]

Comment: We use the SVGs dynamically from an external Uri, we don't use it as a static asset. is there way to do it on-the-fly ?